# Many-Sorted First-Order Logic

Tags: logic

Can you give me an introduction to many-sorted first order logic? How is the syntax and semantics of many-sorted logic defined?

Answer (score 2):

The book "Extensions of first-order logic" by Maria Manzano [http://www.amazon.com/Extensions-First-Order-Cambridge-Theoretical-Computer/dp/0521019028](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521019028) might be valuable, especially if you're coming at things from a computer science perspective.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Enderton, "A mathematical introduction to logic", section 4.3. He provides a careful and detailed explanation of the syntax of a generic many-sorted (first-order) language.